# PyTorch: How to calculate output size of the CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I went through this PyTorch CNN implementation available here: https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/pytorch-conv2d-explained-with-examples/

I am unable to understand how they replace the '?' with some value. What is the formula for calculating the CNN layer output?

This is essential to be calculated in PyTorch; not so in Tensorflow - Keras. If there is any other blog that explains this well, please drop it in the comments.

```
# Implementation of CNN/ConvNet Model
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # L1 ImgIn shape=(?, 28, 28, 1)
        # Conv -> (?, 28, 28, 32)
        # Pool -> (?, 14, 14, 32)
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            torch.nn.Dropout(p=1 - keep_prob))
        # L2 ImgIn shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
        # Conv      ->(?, 14, 14, 64)
        # Pool      ->(?, 7, 7, 64)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            torch.nn.Dropout(p=1 - keep_prob))
        # L3 ImgIn shape=(?, 7, 7, 64)
        # Conv ->(?, 7, 7, 128)
        # Pool ->(?, 4, 4, 128)
        self.layer3 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1),
            torch.nn.Dropout(p=1 - keep_prob))

        # L4 FC 4x4x128 inputs -> 625 outputs
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(4 * 4 * 128, 625, bias=True)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.fc1.weight)
        self.layer4 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            self.fc1,
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Dropout(p=1 - keep_prob))
        # L5 Final FC 625 inputs -> 10 outputs
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(625, 10, bias=True)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight) # initialize parameters

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)   # Flatten them for FC
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out


#instantiate CNN model

model = CNN()
model
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try out this [calculator](https://madebyollin.github.io/convnet-calculator/). So, you need to know number of channels of the output of the conv2d to pass it as input channel to the next conv2d. And number of channels is basically number filters of your conv2d.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you calculation is wrong because:

1. Pytorch support images in format C * H * W  (e.g. 3x32x32 not 32x32x3)
2. First dimension always batch dimension and must be omitted in calculation because, all nn.Modules handle it by default

So if you want calculate input size for first Linear layer, you can use this trick:

```
conv = nn.Sequential(self.layer1,self.layer2, self.layer3, nn.Flatten())
out = conv(torch.randn(1,im_height,im_width).unsqueeze(0)) 
# fc_layer_in_channels  = out.shape[1]
self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(out.shape[1], 625, bias=True)
```

but only if you know `im_height`,`im_width`

The best practice is use  [torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html).
With this layer you always can get output of fixed spatial size.